# Did I ask about Adobe Acrobat here in error?

Tags: discussion, support, migration, unanswered-questions

I am wondering if anyone can help me (perhaps by migration?) find an answer [to the question](https://superuser.com/q/264463/46516) I posed a little over a week ago? It involves changing an Adobe Acrobat pre-packaged template for PDF Packages.

- Is Superuser the right place? (i.e. Is there a different stack it should be migrated to?)
- Should I slap a bounty on it?
- Is it too vague, impossible to make the change I'm looking for (and no one has left a null answer saying so), or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super User is the correct place for your question.

The reason you haven't gotten an answer yet could be many things, but boils down to these main points:

- People who know what you're asking for haven't seen the question
- Those who have seen the question don't know how to solve it

Bounties may or may not help. You're not guaranteed of a solution if you do. You may not even be guaranteed of more views if you do also.

Comment: Do you think the question is sufficiently clear? Would an edit help any?

Comment: It reads fine. Again, sometimes the right people who need to see it haven't seen it. If you tweeted your question or some other social hub to get more eyeballs, that may lead an answer to fall in your lap @mfg

Comment: @mfg see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/

Comment: Thanks I tweeted it yesterday, put it on my blog, and I'm going to try an @Acrobat tweet today.